# How can I access <Image Name="AddImg"/> from Code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I have created an Image in XAML and I would like to access it from code to modify the Source dynamically. I could not access so far. Is there any solution?

```
<Window x:Class="DDSV2.MasterMain"
    Name="MainWw"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DDSV2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MasterMain" Height="1123.439" Width="1822.363" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <ListView x:Name="MainMasterLv" Height="333" Margin="10,10,1494,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="MainMasterLv_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="GridVw">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DataGridCn"  Header="">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTmp">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="AddImg" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources        /gears.png" MaxWidth="80" MaxHeight="80" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

Comment: @Clint You can't do that, because the Image is in a DataTemplate.

Comment: Why do you need to access the Image element from code behind? You can bind any of its properties to properties of the item class that is used by the ListView. Especially `<Image Source="{Binding YourProperty}"/>`. You may of course also use a Binding with a Converter, or even DataTriggers on one or more properties that set the Source property

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the idea. Finally I have used Binding and changed Property value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
   where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null) return null;

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                T childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null) break;
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
```

And use it like :

```
Image item =FindChild<Image>(DataGridCn.CellTemplate.LoadContent(), "AddImg");
string source = item.Source.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use xml methods like xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement image = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Image").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace nsN = image.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("x");
            XAttribute name = image.Attribute(nsN + "Name");
            name.SetValue("newName");
        }
    }
}
```